# Remix debugger: empty screen

Tags: remix, contract-debugging, ganache

I'm running Ganache with a fork of mainnet with Remix - when I try and debug a transaction by clicking on the 'debug' button after sending a transaction, it sends me to the debug screen. When I then skip around using the slider, the debug screen completely goes blank.

Am I doing something wrong here? This always happens so I can't actually debug properly.

[image]

EDIT: Chrome Dev tools shows the following errors when this happens:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing this issue too.

It looked promising at first - I could see the local variables, state variables, stack and opcodes in the debug panel. But when I tried to move through the code (tried step into/over and also the slider) the debug panel just disappeared and I couldn't seem to recover it.

EDIT:
Doing some further digging, my theory is that my local version of the Ganache UI doesn't support methods such as `debug_storageRangeAt` - but looking at the Ganache docs I see it is supported:

https://trufflesuite.github.io/ganache-core/#debug_storageRangeAt

I've updated my Ganache UI app to the latest `v2.5.4` but it still doesn't resolve the bug ‍♂️

I can see there's an open issue with `ganache-cli`:

https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/issues/248

So maybe debugging transactions on Remix via Ganache isn't possible yet?